# Plugin not creating new record, but giving SQL timeout

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've created a plugin to create new records when a field changes on another record. I've set it all up but when I run it no records are created and CRM returns a SQL Timeout error. My code is below:

```
Entity contactSecurityRole = new Entity("sb_contactsecurityrole");
                                contactSecurityRole["sb_contactid"] = linkedContact;
                                contactSecurityRole["sb_contactportalsettingid"] = linkedContactPortalSetting;
                                contactSecurityRole["sb_portalsettingid"] = linkedPortalSetting;
                                contactSecurityRole["sb_portalsecurityroleid"] = linkedSecurityRole;

                                Service.Create(contactSecurityRole);
```

All the variables with a name starting "linked" are entity references to other entities, as the record is made up of lookup fields. I've done some checking and where it stops is where it comes to the actual `Service.Create()` part.

Can someone give me some tips on what to check so I can find why this is happening?

---

### Update:

I've found the issue, and Greg was right it was a problem outside of the code I posted above. The issue was how I was setting up one of my "linked" variables, I was attempting to use a fetch request to retrieve a Guid for the record i needed to link to, from which I was setting up an entityreference.

The mistake I made was thinking that the fetch returned a Guid whereas it was actually returning an entityreference itself. So once I got that fixed the code ran through almost immediately. My guess was that because I was setting it up wrong, when it came to creating the entity CRM/SQL Server could enter the value so it returned the error.

Thanks for everybody's help with this

Comment: You mention in your comments below that this code fires in an update scenario too. Can you confirm is the triggering record referenced anywhere in the code snippet, above? Also, is this plugin registered in the Pre or the Post stage?

Comment: In the section that is causing the error the record triggering the plugin is not referenced, however it is right at the start where a value on the record needs to be a certain value before the rest of the code is triggered. This plugin is registered in the Post stage

Comment: So you simply *check* the value (you're not trying to set it too are you?)

Comment: No thats the only involvement the record has, all the rest is looking to other related entities to get values and create this new record

Comment: I suspect the issue lies outside of your snippet. Did you read through Yacine's link, below? The poster in the linked thread incorrectly (and contrary to SDK advice) had class-level variables which caused problems in some scenarios.

Comment: I've just found out what was wrong and you are correct, it was an issue outside of that code. I've posted what was wrong below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, and Greg was right it was a problem outside of the code I posted above. The issue was how I was setting up one of my "linked" variables, I was attempting to use a fetch request to retrieve a Guid for the record i needed to link to, from which I was setting up an entityreference.

The mistake I made was thinking that the fetch returned a Guid whereas it was actually returning an entityreference itself. So once I got that fixed the code ran through almost immediately. My guess was that because I was setting it up wrong, when it came to creating the entity CRM/SQL Server could enter the value so it returned the error.

Thanks for everybody's help with this

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/crmdevelopment/thread/b27803f5-0bda-4a57-8d6a-e50aaed3767e) will provide you some more clarity and the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I registerd the plugins in Sandbox in one of my CRM instances, which you should be doing, as its good practice. BUT try registering your plugins in non-Sandbox mode and than try creating a record, it might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that any exception would be on the `Service.Create(...` part since this is the point at which the code tries to access CRM (and therefore the underlying SQL table).

Is it possible that you have other plug-ins registered which may be triggered during this process? Are you running on-premise or on-line?

Comment: I've just found that there are a couple of other plugins attached to the entity. They all seem to run on create of a record, while mine runs on both create and update. It still returns the error when it is only being updated. Will having these other plugins registered against the entity, although not triggering at the time, have this kind of result?

Comment: No - if they are not triggered on update then I would expect them to be out of scope of this issue.